# Удалить ссылку внутри изображения

Tags: php, html, link, imagemagick

Все привет! Я получаю ссылку на изображение, внизу которого находится ссылка, причем это не элемент html, а оригинальное изображение. Возможно ли  ссылку удалить с изображения программно или только вручную редактировать?
https://view.publitas.com/50838/1008897/pages/5803d9dd-00a1-42ae-8e23-71cd3079d0de-at1600.jpg

Comment: Если файлов мало, то лучше ручным методом, если много, можно автоматизировать, но 100% гарантии не будет на качество конечного результата. Вы можете скопировать картинку на ваш сервер, обрезать(crop) оригинальный файл и с нижней части добавочно удалить 100px (как пример) и результат сохранить в новую созданную картинку(файл). Будет идеально, если у всех картинок ссылка быдет на одном и том же месте.

Comment: @ДикТополь скопируйте в php-файл [этот](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba8ced23bc929701afd7e6e596b7396e1e1bde87) код, и запустите на вашем сервере. Этот пример не будет универсальным, если изображения разных размеров, и если ссылки в разных местах.